# asp:RegularExpressionValidator, make sure there is no comma in a string

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I've been trying to read about and test various regular expression testers to find my solution but to no avial. I'm using:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
ErrorMessage='<%# "*"%>' ValidationExpression="," runat="server"
ControlToValidate="edit_email" Display="Dynamic" 
EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

All I want to do is find out if there is a comma in the textbox, which this leads me to believe it would do. I tested this on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, as I understand that `EnableClientScript="true"` means I need to have JavaScript compliant RegEx

Any help would be greatly appreciated, here are the other things I've tried:

1. `ValidationExpression=".*\,"` Which
   only hides the error message when I
   have a string followed by a comma at
   the end: "123,"
2. `ValidationExpression=".*,"` Which only hides the error message when I have a string like: "123,"
3. `ValidationExpression=","` Which only hides the error message when I have a string like: "," (only one character, and MUST be a comma)
4. `ValidationExpression="[^,]"` Which only hides the error message when I have a string like: "1" (only one character, and must NOT be a comma)
5. `ValidationExpression="/,/"` Which never hides the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ValidationExpression="[^,]*"
```

That means "zero or more characters, none of which may be a comma"

Comment: Thanks, I knew it couldn't be that difficult, but I felt like I was beginning to exhaust everything.

Comment: What if I wanted to do something similar and make sure that my textbox had one instance of "@" but no more than 50 characters, could you advise me on that one?, I was thinking something like "[^@]+.{0,50}"

Answer (score 1):

How about `.*,.*` ? Do you want to know if there is *at least* one comma or *exactly* one comma?

Comment: I just want to have a message pop up if there are any commas

Comment: OK then my expression is the opposite of what you need - which is indeed Dylan's